# Qual método da tkinter.Entry é responsável por setar o valor da textvariable?

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu criei a seguinte CustomEntry para poder implementar um placeholder:

```
class CustomEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="", cnf={}, fg="black",
        fg_placeholder="grey50", *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(master=None, cnf={}, bg="white", *args, **kw)
        self.fg = fg
        self.fg_placeholder = fg_placeholder
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: self.fill_placeholder())
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: self.clear_box())
        self.fill_placeholder()

    def clear_box(self):
        if not self.get() and super().get():
            self.config(fg=self.fg)
            self.delete(0, tk.END)

    def fill_placeholder(self):
        if not super().get():
            self.config(fg=self.fg_placeholder)
            self.insert(0, self.placeholder)

    def get(self):
        content = super().get()
        if content == self.placeholder:
            return ""
        return content
```

Mas quando especifico uma textvariable e recupero o valor dela recebo meu placeholder como valor, gostaria de saber qual método da Entry está associado ao atributo textvariable para que eu possa sobrescrever o método e evitar que isso aconteça.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema usando a própria textvariable passada para classe, usando o evento  para chamar um método que seta a variável como string vazia caso não haja nenhuma entrada de texto:

```
class CustomEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="", textvariable=None, cnf={}, fg="black",
        fg_placeholder="grey50", *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, cnf={}, bg="white", *args, **kw)
        self.fg = fg
        self.fg_placeholder = fg_placeholder
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.textvariable = textvariable
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: self.fill_placeholder())
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event: self.clear_box())
        self.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: self.set_textvariable())
        self.bind("<Key>", lambda event: self.validate())
        self.fill_placeholder()

    def set_textvariable(self):
        if self.get() != self.placeholder:
            self.textvariable.set(self.get())
        else:
            self.textvariable.set("")

    def clear_box(self):
        if not self.get() and super().get():
            self.config(fg=self.fg)
            self.delete(0, tk.END)

    def fill_placeholder(self):
        if not super().get() and self.placeholder != "":
            self.config(fg=self.fg_placeholder)
            self.insert(0, self.placeholder)

    def get(self):
        content = super().get()
        if content == self.placeholder:
            return ""
        return content
```